# What is the type of string.size() in C++?

Tags: c++, string

I have the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>   
int main()
    {
        std::string s = "458";
        std::cout <<s.size()-4;
    }
```

When I run this I get 42944935 or something like this. But when I run it with the following modification:

```
int main()
{
    std::string s = "458";
    int i = s.size();
    std::cout << i -4;
}
```

I get -1, which I would have expected from the first code. Can someone explain what is happening here?

Comment: What you get is 4294967295, which is 2³²-1 on a 32-bit [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) machine. 4294967295 in an unsigned 32-bit integer and -1 in a signed 32-bit integer have the same bit pattern. [Proof](http://pastebin.com/gfRbeipf).

Comment: What prevented you from looking it up in the documentation?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I can learn more this way.

Comment: No, you will learn more by practising looking things up in the documentation than you will by wildly guessing and having to ask us to spend our time copying the documentation for you every five minutes!

Comment: Nobody forces nobody to look up things from the documentation for me.

Comment: Prior research is a requirement for questions on Stack Overflow. We're not here to do it for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For historical reasons the return type of `std::string::size()` is `size_t`, which is an unsigned type sufficient for the largest possible array size.

You can work around that by defining a number of general size/length-functions, like

```
using Size = ptrdiff_t;  // signed type

template< class Collection >
constexpr auto n_items( Collection const& c )
    -> Size
{ return c.size(); }

// Raw array. Using size_t template param for g++ compatibility.
template< class Item, size_t n >
constexpr auto n_items( Item (&)[n] )
    -> Size
{ return n; }
```

Here I used the name `n_items` because C++17 will define a general `size` function that, unfortunately, returns `size_t` (and conflates a number of notions of size, also unfortunate). One doesn't want a name conflict there.

---

Where you don't have such functions available an alternative is to express a size as the difference of `std::end` and `std::begin`, e.g. `end(s) - begin(s)`. The difference type for raw pointers is `ptrdiff_t` (which is signed), and the default difference type for iterators like you get from `std::string::begin()`, is also `ptrdiff_t`, from `std::iterator_traits`.

Comment: Not only historical reasons I would argue. It just makes more sense to have a size be an unsigned type. A size or a length can't actually be negative.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: That's discussed in many places on SO, in clc++m (archived) and elsewhere. In short it doesn't make sense: it's just an association, like, most sheep are white and so is most processed rice, therefore rice belongs with sheep (not). Counting advantages and disadvantages, there are 0 of the first and many of the latter, in particular that the *modern* promotion rules make implicit conversion up to unsigned type, a bug attractor. Like, `std::string( "Hello" ).length() < -5` is guaranteed to hold. But it's nonsense, a bug.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg For the historical reasons part, at least Carruth and Sutter regret it (https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Interactive-Panel-Ask-Us-Anything 1:02:50; others including Stroustrup himself speaking out against unsigneds in the same video at 9:50, 42:40, but that's not specifically talking about the standard library). So regardless of the stance in the signed vs unsigned discussion, the "historical reasons" part is probably right.

Comment: *"Like, `std::string( "Hello" ).length() < -5` is guaranteed to hold."* That's probably technically implementation defined as `string::size_type` could be a unsigned integer type such that `int` can represent its entire range, in which case the comparison would be false. Not that it matters, no platform does this afaik; just for da lulz.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: I may be wrong, but I believe `std::string` without a custom allocator gets its size type from `std::allocator`, where it's `size_t`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Stuff above holds for `std::size_t` just fine as its type is also implementation defined. Imagine a 32 bit system with a 64 bit `int`. (Yeah, I know, unlikely.)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Automatically converting an impossible value to *some* possible value instead of raising an error does not make sense. Unsigned size types violate the Fail Fast principle.

Answer (score 1):

That happens because the return value of `size()` function is an unsigned value.
When you subtract `-4` from the returned value, the result becomes a negative value. You need to tell `cout` to interpret the value as a signed value (for example, cast the value like this `std::cout <<int(s.size()-4);` or as you have said `int i = s.size();`), then you'll get what you would expect. The reason behind that big integer you get is that if you interpret the binary representation of a **two's complement** negative value as a positive value, it'd be a very big integer value.
To learn more about *two's complement* binary arithmetic you can refer to [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).